Django RESTFRAMEWORK Serializer with nested Serializer
I've got a problem with adding a serializer to another serializer and call it correctly.
My models.py with just the WorkshopMaterials Model
class AmountType(models.TextChoices):
    PCT = "PCT", _("Piece")
    BOX = "BOX", _("Box")
    KG = "KG", _("Kilogram")


class Material(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        STORED = "STORED", _("Stored")
        ORDERED = "ORDERED", _("Ordered")
        NEEDED = "NEEDED", _("Needed")

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=1)
    amountType = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=AmountType.choices,
        default=AmountType.PCT,
        blank=False
    )
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.STORED, blank=False)


class WorkshopMaterials(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    workshop = models.ForeignKey(Workshop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="workshop")
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="material")
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=1)
    amountType = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=AmountType.choices,
        default=AmountType.PCT,
        blank=False
    )

My serializer.py
class MaterialSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Material
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'amount', 'amountType', 'link', 'status')
        extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': True}}


class WorkshopMaterialsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkshopMaterials
        fields = ('amount', 'amountType', 'material', 'workshop')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep["material"] = MaterialSerializer(instance.material).data["name"]
        rep["workshop"] = WorkshopSerializer(instance.workshop).data["id"]

        return rep


class WorkshopSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Workshop
        exclude = ['created_at', 'updated_at']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)

        workshopLeaderData = WorkshopLeaderSerializer(instance.leader).data
        workshopLeaderName = workshopLeaderData["name"]
        if workshopLeaderData["displayname"] == "AN":
            workshopLeaderName = workshopLeaderData["artistname"]

        rep["leader"] = workshopLeaderName

        return rep

My views.py
class MaterialListView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        material = Material.objects.all()
        serializer = MaterialSerializer(material, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MaterialSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)


class WorkshopListView(APIView):
    #permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        ### TESTED MATERIALS FOR DIFFERENT WORKSHOPS
        #workshop = WorkshopMaterials.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('workshop', queryset=Workshop.objects.filter(id=3)))
        #serializer = WorkshopMaterialsSerializer(workshop, many=True)


        ### WORKING FOR LIST VIEW (NO DETAILS)
        #workshops = Workshop.objects.prefetch_related('workshop').all()
        #serializer = WorkshopSerializer(workshops, many=True, fields=('id', 'leader', 'title', 'categorie', 'language'))

        ### NOW TRY TO GET A FULL LIST WITH ALL WORKSHOP FIELDS AND ALL MATERIAL FOR THOSE
        ### CURRENTLY FAILING HERE.
        workshops = Workshop.objects.prefetch_related('workshop').all()
        serializer = WorkshopSerializer(workshops, many=True)

        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    def post(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({'detail': 'WIP'}, status=400)

My current output in JSON Format:
[{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "SPECIAL TITLE",
    "description": "SOME TEXT FOR DESC",
    "categorie": "OTH",
    "language": "EN",
    "duration": "1H",
    "needs_tables": true,
    "participants": "XS",
    "custom_participants": 1,
    "daytime": "ANYT",
    "repeats": "NOREPEAT",
    "location": "BACKLOG",
    "own_material": "",
    "additional_infos": "",
    "costs_currency": "EUR",
    "costs": "0.00",
    "cost_description": "",
    "leader": "COOL LEADER"
}]

My wanted output in JSON Format:
[{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "SPECIAL TITLE",
    "description": "SOME TEXT FOR DESC",
    "categorie": "OTH",
    "language": "EN",
    "duration": "1H",
    "needs_tables": true,
    "participants": "XS",
    "custom_participants": 1,
    "daytime": "ANYT",
    "repeats": "NOREPEAT",
    "location": "BACKLOG",
    "own_material": "",
    "additional_infos": "",
    "costs_currency": "EUR",
    "costs": "0.00",
    "cost_description": "",
    "leader": "COOL LEADER",
    "material": [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Material 1",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Material 2",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Material 3",
        }
    }
}]

How can i use my WorkshopMaterialsSerializer to work with my WorkshopSerializer to get my the output i want? And how can i handle it on the performance side? Currently i tried to Prefetch

You can get that json structure like this.
You just need to query all the materials from the WorkshopMaterials modal in the get_material SerializerMethodField method and then pass that to a slightly updated WorkhopMaterialSerializer
You can leave your old MaterialSerializer untouched, since its being used by another view.
class WorkhopMaterialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='material.id')
    name = serializers.CharField(source='material.name')

    class Meta:
        model = WorkshopMaterials
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': True}}

class WorkshopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    material = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Workshop
        exclude = ['created_at', 'updated_at']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if fields is not None:
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        workshopLeaderData = WorkshopLeaderSerializer(instance.leader).data
        workshopLeaderName = workshopLeaderData["name"]
        if workshopLeaderData["displayname"] == "AN":
            workshopLeaderName = workshopLeaderData["artistname"]
        rep["leader"] = workshopLeaderName
        return rep

    def get_material(self, instance):
        workshop_materials = WorkshopMaterials.objects.filter(workshop_id=instance.id)
        return WorkhopMaterialSerializer(workshop_materials, many=True).data

Add the required imports, etc and I am assuming this is how your fields are for Material model.
material.id and material.name

This solved my problem on the Workshop View, but now my MaterialList View is broken.
(I've added the material Model and View to the main question).
I'm using a MaterialSerialiser like this now: Pastbin, because the format in comments is... special

The pastbin url seems to be expired. Can you tell me what issue you are facing with the MaterialList View?

The correct pastbin
And the Error im facing:
AttributeError at /api/workshop/material_list
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field id on serializer MaterialSerializer.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the Material instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'id'.

Okay, seems like you have another view using MaterialSerializer, So when I implemented mine (I assumed it was not being used by anything else).
I'll update the answer.

Is WorkshopMaterialsSerializer being used by any view?

For the moment, no. But i want to implement one later.

Hey, since i've no reputation to start a chat, i need to ask here if you got any idea whats failing. I didn't got a solution working for both. Either the MaterialListView is working or my WorkshopListView.
